# Change button opacity of buttons that are not clicked

Tags: javascript, button, opacity

Hi I've got a question in how I would change the opacity of a list of buttons where if a button is clicked, the opacity of the rest of the buttons would change to 0.5. And the one that was clicked would remain at 1.

So far I've got the below where I can change the opacity of the button that's clicked but struggling to achieve what I've said above. In jquery I know you can use .not(this) but not sure how to do this is JS.

EDIT : In my buttons I also have a span tag which holds the copy. When you click on the span tag this looks to cause issues with the opacity as well.

Button would like this, my apologies for not adding this in at the start

```html
<button class="variantClass">
<span>Button</span> 
</button
```

```js
var buttonSelector = document.querySelectorAll('button.variantClass');
buttonSelector.forEach(function (el){
  el.addEventListener("click", function(){
    this.style.opacity = "0.5";
  })
});
```

```css
.variantClass { background: black; color: white; padding: 30px;}
```

```html
<button class="variantClass">
Button 
</button>
<button class="variantClass">
Button 
</button>
<button class="variantClass">
Button 
</button>
<button class="variantClass">
Button 
</button>
<button class="variantClass">
Button 
</button>
<button class="variantClass">
Button 
</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var buttonSelector = document.querySelectorAll('button.variantClass');
buttonSelector.forEach(function (el){
  el.addEventListener("click", function(ev){
    buttonSelector.forEach(function(button) { button.style.opacity = '0.5' })
    this.style.opacity = 1
  })
});
```

```css
.variantClass { background: black; color: white; padding: 30px;}
```

```html
<button class="variantClass">
<span>Button</span>
</button>
<button class="variantClass">
<span>Button</span>
</button>
<button class="variantClass">
<span>Button</span>
</button>
<button class="variantClass">
<span>Button</span>
</button>
<button class="variantClass">
<span>Button</span>
</button>
<button class="variantClass">
<span>Button</span>
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks @bel3atar for your answer, works exactly how I want but could you explain what you've done so I can learn from this?

Comment: I simply set the opacity of all the buttons to 0.5, then I set the opacity of the clicked button to 1

Comment: thanks for this @bel3atar One last question in my code I have a span tag within the button, and looks if you click on the span the opacity of this changes and not the entire button (think it's because of the .target event) have you got any idea of how to solve this issue? So the button would be: <button class="variantClass">
<span>Button</span> 
</button>

Comment: I updated the answer, the event.target points to the actual element that was clicked. Since the click event will eventually bubble up to the button, using `this `solves the problem

Comment: Thanks @bel3atar ended up figuring this out myself after making some changes myself but thanks for the reply and with your answer

Comment: Sorry @bel3atar, is there another way of writing this code without the => arrow function. I seem to get an error use eversion 6

Comment: yeah just replace it with a normal function

Comment: I've tried doing this but not able to get it working, are you able to help with this @bel3atar

Comment: Ah yes, I was misplacing my ending } bracket. Thanks again @bel3atar